# Is there a way to read config values in dynamics ax using X++ code?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have edited an app.config file in AX since I want to change the service endpoint to connect to specific server. (i.e QA server). But I got an error saying applicationId does not have any value but looking at the config file there clearly is a value for the applicationId node. Now I want to read the config file using X++ so I can see the values when I debug the code.
Is there a way to read config values in dynamics ax using X++ code?

Answer (score 0):

The class library's config file is stored in the model store and downloaded by the client/server. It can't be changed unless it's changed in the AOT and the Visual Studio project is rebuilt, at which point the client/server will download the new version from the model store.

You need to change the URL at run time.

See here http://daxmusings.codecrib.com/2011/10/consuming-external-webservices-in-ax.html . Scroll to the bottom of that post and see the last few paragraphs and how he does it in the job to change to your QA server.

Comment: essentially I have the same code with the link you provide but I am trying to solve the error I got. Please supply the ApplicationId you were given in the header for your client endpoint: <headers><ApplicationId xmlns="my-company">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ApplicationId></headers> the code works, it could get/set the endpoint address but I don't understand why it could not get the applicationId.